# Issue with creating grouped tableview using JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Essentially I am creating a UITableView that gets its cell info from JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

First it's better to use

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let customer, serial, rma, model: String
    let manufacturer: String
}
```

---

```
let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
let dic = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.customer}) // [String:[Root]]
```

> numberOfsections

```
dic.keys.count
```

and

> numberofRows

```
let keys = Array(dic.keys)

let item = dic[keys[section]]!

return item.count
```

Comment: Where does `struct Root: Codable {
    let customer, serial, rma, model: String
    let manufacturer: String
}` go?